# Can this number be rational?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $K = e^{-\gamma}\log\log n$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $n\geq 2$ is a positive integer. Can $K$ be rational for any integer $n\geq 2$ ?

I seem not to find any argument to prove or refute this.

Comment: We don't even know if the Euler-Mascheroni constant is rational, so how could we know if $K$ is rational?

Comment: @GregoryGrant But is it known that $\log{\log{n}}$ is not rational?